# Securing/Locking down/Approval mechanics for Windows?

Tags: windows-10, security, blocking, lock, whitelist

I'm looking for way on how to lock down my system so I wouldn't really need an antivirus, I wonder if Windows can do this by itself? Or what other solutions are available?

What I want Windows to do is, give me something like an UAC prompt, where I can "Deny", "Allow Always" or "Allow Once" for actions like:

- Process creation (if a white-listed executable has been modified, re-ask for permission)
- Creation/Modification of startup entries (either in registry or on the file system)
- Creation/Modification of scheduled tasks
- Creation/Modification of services
- Creation/Modification of driver entries
- Creation/Modification of specific registry locations

This way I can have full control over my Windows machine and no app, installer or anything can do something that I wouldn't want it to do to my PC. Everything must be approved explicitly.

Is it possible to change some settings / do something in Windows to achieve this?

Are there other solutions to achieve this?

A nice + would be also to set filters, for example: allowed commandline parameters, and all other commandline parameters would need ask permission to run for processes (and similar filters for all other points).

Comment: You still need AV to scan files you download or are downloaded in the background (cache).  The majority of infections today are drive by downloads very few malicious files are intentionally downloaded by the user

Comment: Yeah I will keep using one ofcourse, but I want to be even more secure, for stuff my AV can't protect me from (like false negatives). I know in XP days you could use `SecureWave Sanctuary Suite`, but isn't something like that in Windows 10 nowadays? Or other solutions? XP isn't really recommended as an OS nowadays.